# How to use Ransack Aliases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I am trying to implement aliases with Ransack to make my URL search query shorter.

According to the docs:
https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#ransack-aliases

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author

  # Abbreviate :author_first_name_or_author_last_name to :author
  ransack_alias :author, :author_first_name_or_author_last_name
end
```

However when i use it in my model, i get a

```
undefined method `ransack_alias' for #<Class:0x007f9376f176e0>
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, `ransack_alias` appeared in the master branch of the ransack, in 1.7.0(current stable) it was not implemented.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the latest updates, use the `master` branch.

```
gem 'ransack', github: 'activerecord-hackery/ransack'
```

Answer (score 1):

method `ransack_alias` was appeared in v 1.8.0

[Ransack 1.8.0 changelog](http://www.example.com/https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/releases/tag/v1.8.0)

update your Gemfile gem version

```
gem 'ransack', '~> 1.8.0'
```