# Ransack And Column Alias

Tags: activerecord, ransack

In our controller logic, we have to create a few column aliases for a special class of object (Which is a compilation of many objects):
[image]

The trouble is, when trying to ransack, ransack will ignore the alias and try to go to the original table.column_name. SQL after ransack:

> > "SELECT  CONCAT_WS('
> >     **',users.first_name,users.middle_name,users.last_name) AS conducted_by**,
> >     COUNT(NULLIF(is_complete = false,true)) as complete_count,
> >     COUNT(staff_assessments.id) as employee_count,
> >     staff_assessment_groups.name as name,
> >     MIN(staff_assessments.created_at) as created_at,
> >     staff_assessment_groups.id as staff_assessment_group_id,
> >     staff_assessment_groups.effective_date as effective_date,
> >     staff_assessment_groups.effective_date as review_date, 'N/A' as
> >     store_names, true as is_complete, true as is_360_evaluation,
> >     \"staff_assessments\".\"assigner_position_id\" FROM
> >     \"staff_assessments\" INNER JOIN \"positions\" ON \"positions\".\"id\"
> >     = \"staff_assessments\".\"assigner_position_id\" AND \"positions\".\"deleted_at\" IS NULL INNER JOIN \"employees\" ON
> >     \"employees\".\"id\" = \"positions\".\"employee_id\" AND
> >     \"employees\".\"deleted_at\" IS NULL INNER JOIN \"users\" ON
> >     \"users\".\"id\" = \"employees\".\"user_id\" AND
> >     \"users\".\"deleted_at\" IS NULL INNER JOIN
> >     \"staff_assessment_groups\" ON \"staff_assessment_groups\".\"id\" =
> >     \"staff_assessments\".\"staff_assessment_group_id\" INNER JOIN
> >     \"survey_types\" ON \"survey_types\".\"id\" =
> >     \"staff_assessments\".\"survey_type_id\" INNER JOIN
> >     \"survey_type_categories_types\" ON \"survey_types\".\"id\" =
> >     \"survey_type_categories_types\".\"survey_type_id\" WHERE
> >     \"staff_assessments\".\"position_id\" IN (12024,) AND
> >     \"staff_assessments\".\"is_360_evaluation\" = 't' AND
> >     \"survey_type_categories_types\".\"survey_type_category_id\" = 3 AND
> >     **\"staff_assessments\".\"conducted_by\" IN ('Bart  Simpson')** GROUP BY
> >     users.id, \"staff_assessments\".\"assigner_position_id\",
> >     staff_assessment_groups.id ORDER BY
> >     staff_assessment_groups.effective_date DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0"

(Note the bold conducted_by--that was the original ransack search, but it is using staff_assessments.name instead of the aliased 'name' above)

So here is my question--is there way to tell ransack to use the aliased field? Or is there a way to simply create the records as an Active Relation

(Tried putting the objects to an array, but I could no longer ransack it)

Comment: Found the answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34738623/how-to-use-ransack-aliases